# Prevent TYPO3 CMS from expanding added media relation per default

Tags: configuration, typo3, typo3-8.x

Is it possible to configure TYPO3 CMS to prevent it from expanding a media relation which is added to a page by default? Now each time a new media relation is added the detail view will be expanded.

I have checked the TSconfig docs and the install tool settings, but I did not find any related documentation or any similar question here on Stack Overflow.

[image: expanded media relation after adding it to the page]

Comment: I think that the correct property could be "collapseAll" (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/8-dev/ColumnsConfig/Properties/InlineAppearance.html?highlight=collapseall; https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/8-dev/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline.html?highlight=collapseall#file-abstraction-layer)
I don't know now how it should be used. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see from the code there is no possibility to do that. 
The options Riccardo mentioned in the comment only work when opening a record with existing relations.

Your case (creating new relation) is handled via `typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Controller/FormInlineAjaxController.php`

in combination with

`web/typo3/sysext/backend/Resources/Public/JavaScript/jsfunc.inline.js` -> `inline.domAddNewRecord`

there are no options to prevent expansion - only collapsing all other elements is possible (via `expandSingle` TCA configuration).